# to create a header file to scan integer without using stdio.h(scanf)

Tags: c, assembly

I need to create a header file for function `int read_int()`, which scans an integer and returns it, without using `scanf`.

I have some knowledge on extended asm. I dont exactly know how to scan elements through the function **asm__volatile** .

down is the code i used for printing an integer (without using stdio.h).working perfectly

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movl $4, %%eax \n\t"
    "movl $1, %%ebx \n\t"
    "int $128 \n\t"
    :
    :"c"(buff), "d"(bytes)
) ; // $4: write, $1: on stdin
```

Comment: Why can't you use scanf?

Comment: @jonsca i cannot use getchar either because it is a function of stdio.h.

Comment: @bazinga Yes, I reread.  Sorry.

Comment: If you can't use stdio to read the individual characters, then you probably need to tell what OS you want to write this for, as you'll need to do something OS-specific to read in the raw data.

Comment: @jerry i m using linux OS. i addded a part of code which i used for printing an integer.

Comment: Note that on 64bit, you should use sysenter instead of int.  sysenter uses different registers.

Answer (score 1):

Which part is causing you trouble? Reading data from standard input is done using the `read` system call (see [here](http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html) for a list of syscalls on x86 linux) similar to the way you're using `write` to print:

```
int my_fgets(char* s, int size, int fd) {
    int nread;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "int $0x80\n\t"
    : "=a" (nread)
    : "a" (3), "b" (fd), "c" (s), "d" (size)
    );
    return nread;
}
```

Implementing your own `getchar` (should you so desire) using the above function is straight forward.

If it's the 'scanning' and reading of the integer that you're having trouble with, it can be done using the above function:

```
#define MY_STDIN 0
int read_int() {
    char buffer[256];
    int nr, number;

    nr = my_fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), MY_STDIN);
    if (nr < 1) {
        /* error */
    }
    buffer[nr - 1] = 0; // overwrite newline

    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "mov $0, %0\n\t" // initialize result to zero
        "1:\n\t" // inner loop
        "movzx (%%esi), %%eax\n\t" // load character
        "inc %%esi\n\t" // increment pointer
        "and %%eax, %%eax\n\t"
        "jz 2f\n\t" // if character is NUL, done
        "sub $'0', %%eax\n\t" // subtract '0' from character
        "add %%eax, %0\n\t" // add to result
        "jmp 1b\n\t" // loop
        "2:\n\t"
    : "=q" (number)
    : "S" (buffer)
    : "eax" // clobber eax
    );
    return number;
}
```

As this is for homework the above function is incomplete and will only work for the numbers 0 to 9, though extending it should be trivial.